# Magic? Where does the React Context Provider come from? Naming convention?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, react-context

I am using firebase auth in my app and it's working - however I'm struggling to understand how the provider passes data into the App component in App.js.
It doesn't appear to be passed in explicitly. Is there a naming convention or something that's passing the data?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import firebase from './firebase'
import withFirebaseAuth from 'react-with-firebase-auth'

import SignInPage from './SignInPage'
import AppContainer from './AppContainer'

const firebaseAppAuth = firebase.auth();

function App(provider){
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {
          provider.user // if user from the provider
          ? <AppContainer 
                authUser={provider.user}
                signOut={provider.signOut}
              />
            : <SignInPage 
              signInWithGoogle={provider.signInWithGoogle}
              error={provider.error}
              />
        }
    </div>
  );
}



const providers = {
  googleProvider: new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
};

export default withFirebaseAuth({
  providers,
  firebaseAppAuth,
})(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the provider from the HOC `withFirebaseAuth`. It wraps your component. That's why you can use the provider even though you didn't pass it, the HOC 'provided' it.

Comment: Thank you :-) Is there any declaration or way to tell that it's a HOC and passing data in?